# How to mock protected subclass method inherited from abstract class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

How to use Mockito or PowerMock to mock a protected method that is realized by a subclass, but inherited from an abstract super class?

In other words, I want to test "doSomething" method while mocking the "doSomethingElse".

**Abstract super class**

```
public abstract class TypeA {

    public void doSomething() {     

        // Calls for subclass behavior
        doSomethingElse();      
    }

    protected abstract String doSomethingElse();

}
```

**Subclass implementation**

```
public class TypeB extends TypeA {

    @Override
    protected String doSomethingElse() {
        return "this method needs to be mocked";
    }

}
```

***Solution***

Answers given here are correct and will work if classes involved are in the same package.

But if **different packages** are involved one option is to user PowerMock. The following example worked for me. Of course there might be other ways of doing it, this is one that works.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ TypeB.class })
public class TestAbstract {

    @Test
    public void test_UsingPowerMock() throws Exception {
        // Spy a subclass using PowerMock
        TypeB b = PowerMockito.spy(new TypeB());
        String expected = "some value for mock";

        // Mock a method by its name using PowerMock again
        PowerMockito.doReturn(expected).when(b, "doSomethingElse");

        // Calls the 
        String actual = b.doSomething();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);     

    }
}
```

Note: *Tests done using Java 5, jUnit 4.11, Mockito 1.9.0 and PowerMock 1.4.12.*

Comment: This approach gives me a `NullPointerException` with Java 8, JUnit 4.12, and PowerMock 1.6.4.

Comment: @Mack did you solve it?

Comment: @ceyun I apologize but it's been so long I don't recall if I solved it, or if I did, how. Perhaps one of the individuals who upvoted my comment recall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` when mocking the abstract method. This will call the originals methods of the class and you can mock all abstract methods by yourself.

```
TypeA typeA = mock(TypeA.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
when(typeA.doSomethingElse()).thenReturn("Hello");
typeA.doSomething();
```

Or you test directly on the TypeB with a spy:

```
TypeB typeB = spy(new TypeB());
when(typeB.doSomethingElse()).thenReturn("Hello");
typeB.doSomething();
```

Comment: The 1st option fails because TypeA is abstract. Option 2 works with `spy()` but when I try to apply it into my production code it gives me `The method <method name> from the type <subclass name> is not visible`. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: Actually your test is correct, but I have classes that are in different packages, that is why I was not able to do it earlier. Methods are not visible from other packages when protected.

Comment: Did the 1st option works too? I have tested both with Mockito 1.10.19 and latest beta version and both work as expected.

Comment: Indeed it works. Forgot to tell you my Mockito version is ancient, 1.9.0, because of Java 5.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using Mockito for that:

```
// Create a new Mock
final TypeA a = Mockito.mock(TypeA.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

// Call the method
a.doSomething();

// Now verify that our mocked class' method was called
Mockito.verify(a, Mockito.times(1)).doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: It works, but I just realized that I have classes in different packages in my production code. Protected methods are not visible then.

Comment: This makes it a problem. A possible solution would be to use PowerMock, which should be able to verify private methods, afaik. Never used it, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can test your abtract class using mockito in the following way

```
TypeA typA = Mockito.mock(TypeA.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
when(typA.doSomethingElse()).thenReturn("doSomethingElse");
Assert.assertSomething(typeA.doSomething());
```

Answer (score 0):

To mock methods that returns void in abstract classes we could use:

```
MyAbstractClass abs = Mockito.mock(MyAbstractClass.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(abs).myMethod(arg1,arg2....));
```

We can replace arguments with Mockito.anyString() etc as per requirements.